# SQL Server Filtering JOIN Data

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I have two tables for my process instrument data,
First table has the Machine ID, Tripping Time, Tripping reason

```
Machine ID  Trip Time              Trip Reason
XA-065      03-20-2014 09:40:098    ANY
XA-065      03-24-2014 18:33:040    ANY
XA-765      03-23-2014 22:16:002    ANY
XA-070      03-21-2014 15:17:023    ANY
```

Second table has the Machine ID , Starting time.

```
Machine ID  Start Time             Operator
XA-065      03-20-2014 12:40:098    ANY
XA-065      03-24-2014 20:33:040    ANY
XA-765      03-23-2014 23:16:002    ANY
XA-070      03-21-2014 18:17:023    ANY
```

I’ve to join the two tables, So, for each machine I can get Machine ID,Trip Time, Start Time, and then I can add a calculated column to get the downtime "Start Time-Trip Time"
The problem is, when the same machine starts and trips several times, JOIN operation matches all possible Trip/Start combinations. Which results in wrong downtime calculations.
This is the result of My Join, notice what happens with Machine XA-065 :

```
Machine ID  Trip Time               Start Time              Downtime
XA-065      03-20-2014 09:40:098    03-20-2014 12:40:098    3 Hours
XA-065      03-20-2014 09:40:098    03-24-2014 20:33:040    **11 hours**
XA-065      03-24-2014 18:33:040    03-20-2014 12:40:098    **-6 Hours**
XA-065      03-24-2014 18:33:040    03-24-2014 20:33:040    2 Hours
XA-765      03-23-2014 22:16:002    03-23-2014 23:16:002    1 Hour
XA-070      03-21-2014 15:17:023    03-21-2014 18:17:023    3 Hours
```

Because JOIN will take all possible combinations for same Machine ID, I’m getting wrong data,11 Hours, -6 hours for downtime "Second and Third Rows".
How can I filter JOIN operation in order to get rid of this ?
I sorted the two tables in a descending orders, so, the right values come first, but still I’m getting wrong JOINED rows.

Your help is highly appreciated.
A.A

Comment: If I understand your situation correctly, each "Start Time" in the second table corresponds to exactly one "Trip Time" in the first table. Then your DB schema is wrong to begin with; you should have them all in one table.

Comment: When a condition like this occurs, which record(s) do you want filtered out? IOW, what results are you expecting for machine `XA-065` in this example? Should `Start Time` *always* be later than `Trip Time` to produce valid results?

Comment: I'm expecting the first and third rows only,                      XA-065      03-20-2014 09:40:098    03-20-2014 12:40:098   3Hours XA-065      03-24-2014 18:33:040    03-24-2014 20:33:040    2 Hours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. but the results can really differ if you have only one missing record in either of the tables.

**Query**

```
SELECT A.MachineID
      ,A.TripTime
      ,B.StartTime
      ,DATEDIFF(HOUR, A.TripTime,B.StartTime) AS DownTime
FROM 
  (
  SELECT * 
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MachineID ORDER BY TripTime ASC) AS RN
  FROM dbo.MachineTrip
  ) A
      INNER JOIN
  (
   SELECT * 
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MachineID ORDER BY StartTime ASC) AS RN
   FROM dbo.MachineStart
   )B
ON A.MachineID = B.MachineID AND A.RN = B.RN
```

**Result Set**

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╦══════════╗
║ MachineID ║        TripTime         ║        StartTime        ║ DownTime ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬══════════╣
║ XA-065    ║ 2014-03-20 09:40:00.097 ║ 2014-03-20 12:40:00.097 ║        3 ║
║ XA-065    ║ 2014-03-24 18:33:00.040 ║ 2014-03-24 20:33:00.040 ║        2 ║
║ XA-070    ║ 2014-03-21 15:17:00.023 ║ 2014-03-21 18:17:00.023 ║        3 ║
║ XA-765    ║ 2014-03-23 22:16:00.003 ║ 2014-03-23 23:16:00.003 ║        1 ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╩══════════╝
```

### [`Working SQL FIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3041c/1)

**Suggestion**

Your schema needs some serious attention. You should really have a foreign key constraint between these two tables which binds a record in one table to a record in other table.

*OR*

You can have all the records in one table with a column which binds two related rows together and a column (Maybe a bit column) which indicates whether a record is starttime or triptime.

Your schema as it is very much error prone.

Comment: Well, I'm really thankful for your answer "Didn't try it yet", I never did even a SQL query and I don't know what is a schema, I tried to create a primary, foreign key for the tables but I couldn't. I think I should read about this, and I'll appreciate if you would suggest a source to start with.

Comment: Not a problem but remember when you are working/learning to work with any RDBMS , You must have a very good understanding of foreign key/ relationships between tables. If you dont know this its like learning to fly a plane without knowing how to take off from runway :).  Read this here [`FOREIGN KEY Constraints`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with join and aggregation.  This is a bit more robust if you have missing records or multiple start records in a row.

```
select mt.MachineId, mt.TripTime, min(ms.StartTime) as StartTime,
       datediff(hour, mt.TripTime, min(ms.StartTime)) as HoursDifference
from MachineTrip mt join
     MachineStart ms
     on mt.MachineId = ms.MachineId and
        mt.TripTime < ms.StartTime
group by mt.MachineId, mt.TripTime;
```

Note I used the same naming conventions as Ali so you can try it on that SQL Fiddle.